# Adding a grid to ecdf generated plot so it will be behind the graph curve

Tags: r

I am using the following code to generate an ecdf plot:

```
plot(xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,1), main=NULL, xaxs="i", yaxs="i", ecdf(PrecentageVector), col="red", do.p = FALSE, pch=19, lwd=3)
grid()
```

The result is that the grid lines are being draw on the curve. If I switch the order the grid lines are not seen at all. I would the like the grid lines to be drawn behind the curve line. How could this be achieved?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use the `panel.first` argument within the `plot` function:

```
plot(xlim=c(0,100), ylim=c(0,1), main=NULL, xaxs="i", yaxs="i",
  ecdf(PrecentageVector), col="red", do.p = FALSE, pch=19, lwd=3,
  panel.first = grid())
```